# Hibernate transaction begin and commit at the right point

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a dao package where all my DaoClasses implements amongst others the following methode:

```
public class XDaoImpl implements XDao {

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Override
    public void saveOrUpdate(MyObject o) {
            //Transaction trans = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().beginTransaction();
            getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(o); 
            //trans.commit();
        }
}
```

If I run my application it needs a lot time to store my objects to the database. I belief it happens because I create a new Transaction for each object. So I tried to use Spring Framework’s xml based declarative transaction implementation. But till now it does not work for me:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
     xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd">

    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location">
            <value>/resources/spring/config/database.properties</value>
        </property>
    </bean>


    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="hibernate3SessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">

        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

        <property name="mappingResources">
            <list>
                <value>/resources/spring/config/A.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>/resources/spring/config/B.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>/resources/spring/config/C.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>/resources/spring/config/D.hbm.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>

    </bean>

    <bean id="dBo" class="com.model.bo.DBoImpl">
        <property name="dDao" ref="dDao" />
        <property name="bDao" ref="bDao" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dDao" class="com.model.dao.dDaoImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate3SessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="aBo" class="com.model.bo.aBoImpl">
        <property name="aDao" ref="aDao" />
        <property name="bDao" ref="bDao" />
        <property name="cDao" ref="cDao" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="bDao" class="com.model.dao.bDaoImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate3SessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="cDao" class="com.model.dao.cDaoImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate3SessionFactory" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="aDao" class="com.model.dao.aDaoImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate3SessionFactory" />
    </bean>

     <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate3SessionFactory" />
    </bean>
    <tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
        <tx:attributes>
            <tx:method name="get*" read-only="true" />
            <tx:method name="*" propagation="REQUIRED" />
        </tx:attributes>
    </tx:advice>
    <aop:config>
        <aop:pointcut id="boMethods" expression="execution(* com.model.bo.*.*(..))" />

        <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="boMethods" />
    </aop:config> 
    </beans>
```

The error that is thrown:

> class org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException Error
>   creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource
>   [resources/spring/config/BeanLocations.xml]: BeanPostProcessor before
>   instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultBeanFactoryPointcutAdvisor#0':
>   Cannot resolve reference to bean 'boMethods' while setting bean
>   property 'pointcut'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'boMethods': Instantiation of bean failed;
>   nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/aspectj/weaver/BCException

```
public class DBoImpl implements DBo {

    private DDao dDao;
    private BDao bDao;


    public DDao getDDao() {
        return dDao;
    }

    public void setDDao(DDao dDao) {
        this.dDao = dDao;
    }

    public BDao getbDao() {
        return bDao;
    }

    public void setbDao(BDao bDao) {
        this.bDao = bDao;
    }

public D add(D r) {
        dDao.saveOrUpdate(r);
        return r;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't have the AOP jar files in your class path.

See:
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html

Look for the section "10.2.1 Enabling @AspectJ Support"

Comment: Thx, do I have also provide a Getter and Setter method for a Transaction object and add it to my aBo- and dBo-Bean compare to that my Dao-Beans contains the sessionFactory?

Comment: And did I use the lines `Transaction trans = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().beginTransaction();
        trans.commit();` any more? I ask because I delete those lines and get the error: _class org.hibernate.HibernateException
saveOrUpdate is not valid without active transaction_

Comment: I believe that is correct. You should just have to call getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(). It could be an issue with the aop config, although so far it looks good to me...still looking through it.

Comment: Is the aop expression correct? Are the daos that need transaction support in com.model.bo or com.model.dao. I see a few daos defined that are in com.model.dao. You may want to try changing the expression to `execution(* com.model.dao.*.*(..))`

Comment: Please see my edits, I add examples for my dao classes and bo classes.

Comment: What package is XDaoImpl in? If your aop expression is set to `com.model.bo.*`, but XDaoImpl is in `com.model.dao.*` then the transaction won't be weaved in properly. You would need to change the expression to `<aop:pointcut id="boMethods" expression="execution(* com.model.dao.*.*(..))" />`

Comment: I run my application with `expression="execution(* com.model.dao.*.*(..))"` and run into the same error: _class org.hibernate.HibernateException
saveOrUpdate is not valid without active transaction_

Answer (score 0):

Using AOP for transactional behavior is fine. I'd suggest having a look at [annotation based configuration](http://www.studytrails.com/frameworks/spring/spring-declarative-transactions-annotation.jsp) (Note the `<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />`), which might be a little bit more straightforward.

Furthermore I would be careful about using this configuration. A transaction is meant to encapsulate an atomic unit of work. Having a method like `saveOrUpdate(EntityType entity)` I'd think your atomic unit of work was saving one entity, not saving n entities. The longer a transaction runs, the greater gets the probability of running into deadlocks.

I'd suggest creating a Method like public void saveOrUpdateInBatch(MyObject... objects). The name implies you are dealing with an atomic operation which handles a number of elements. Also you might want to optimize this method for batch inserts.

Comment: Did you mentioned in your second paragraph that if I use aop configuration instead of creating a Transaction object inside the methode saveOrUpdate will nothing change to the performance?

Comment: No, your new configuration will improve performance as Spring will create one transaction which will be used for subsequent calls as well. Creating transactions on you own should be avoided altogether, that's a job spring can handle in a clean and beautiful way for you. Creating a distinct method for batch update would be a cleaner approach in my opinion though.

Comment: Now that I think about it I'm not that sure whether spring will re-use the transaction, if you call your saveOrUpdate method from outside the spring context. If I remember correctly, your calling method would have to be declared as transactional method in order to get a peformance impact. That being said, everything would be cleaner if you'd have a specialized method for doing batch updates.

Comment: I try to use annotation I changed my LocationBean to `<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">  
  <property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate3SessionFactory" />
 </bean>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />`
and put the line `@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)` before all my class defintions in the packages bo and dao. It came up with the same error: _class org.hibernate.HibernateException
saveOrUpdate is not valid without active transaction_

Comment: Please remove <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop> from your applicationcontext.xml. That seems to be the problem according to http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/40162-transactional-and-hibernate-transaction-problem